# Passing an array of ints with node-soap

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, soap, node-soap

I'm using [node-soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) with a service and everything works but I need to send an array of ints and I find that I can only send the first one because I can't find the correct way to build a JS object to represent this array.

I've been looking at [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865128/send-a-request-with-arrays-in-node-soap-node-js) but I couldn't find the answer to my question.

I need to generate a XML property like the following one:

```
<ns1:ArrayOfInts>
          <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
          <arr:int>2904</arr:int>
          <arr:int>3089</arr:int>
          <arr:int>4531</arr:int>
</ns1:ArrayOfInts>
```

by passing an object that contains the array:

```
soapObject = {
              somefields,
              "ns1:ArrayOfInts": {
                 Something goes here
              },
             };
```

Any idea how to create the JS object?

Comment: maybe you need to pass an array inside the "ns1:ArrayOfInts" like 
soapObject= {
some:"field",
ArrayOfInts: [2904,3089,4531]
};

Comment: I tried that and it's close but it doesn't include the "arr" namespace prefix which is needed later by the WSDL method, i.e.: <ns1:ArrayOfInts><int>2904</int><int>3089</int></ns:ArrayOfInts>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and used `$xml` property to add raw XML to the request and `attributes` to set the `arr` namespace:

```
var fields = [2904, 3089, 4531];
soapObject.arrayOfInts = {
    attributes: {
        'xmlns:arr': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'
    },
    $xml: fields.map(function(value) {
        return '<arr:int>' + value + '</arr:int>';
    }).join('')
};
```

This code will generate the following request:

```
<ns1:arrayOfInts xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <arr:int>2904</arr:int>
    <arr:int>3089</arr:int>
    <arr:int>4531</arr:int>
</ns1:arrayOfInts>
```